# Keyboard can only type qwfjzn

Tags: keyboard

I am new to Ubuntu. My keyboard often get stuck and refuse to type any keyword except the one in "qwfjzn" (Not all the time but quite often).

It can happen in any program from taskbar to slack to any input in webpage.

It also happens randomly since I can still type at other place that it isn't limit to only "qwfjzn".

If I don't do anything for 1-2 minutes. It go back to normal.

Version is: 22.04.3 LTS

Have anyone face this before